# Configure workers processes in AWS Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, heroku

I have two worker processes setup in a node.js app, I have configured the processes in the **Procfile**

```
worker: npm run-script reportservice
```

And in
**package.json**

```
"scripts": {   
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",  
    "reportservice": "nodemon --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=920 --gc_interval=100 --exec babel-node report.service.js"
  }
```

And **report.service.js** looks like this,

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const createServer = require('./server');

const { Scheduler } = require('./utils/request.scheduler');

const app = createServer();

dotenv.config();
const server = app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('app listening at port %s', 8000);
});


cron.schedule(

  `0 */10 * * * *`,
  async () => {
    Scheduler.createReport();
  }
);


module.exports = server;
```

This is running fine in Heroku, i.e. this is running in a separate container every 10 mins. My question is how do we configure the profile in the AWS Kubernetes cluster?